# Proving stationairty of AR(1)

Tags: autoregressive

Let me set this up. We have an AR(1) process: $x_1 = w_1$ and $x_t = \frac{1}{2}x_{t-1} + w_t$ for $t \geq 2$ and where the $w_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

I have read that this process is stationary - and I can see that by looking at the roots of the characteristic polynomial using the backshift operator - but I'm having a bit of trouble in proving stationarity without using this. I have seen several answers online, but nothing which has soundly hit home yet.

Some answers I have seen have used properties of stationarity to prove it - like proving the variance is constant by using the property that Var($x_t$) = Var($x_{t-1}$). For example,

Var($x_t$) = Var($\frac{1}{2}x_{t-1} + w_t$) = Var($\frac{1}{2}x_{t-1}$) + Var($w_t$) = $\frac{1}{4}$Var($x_{t-1}$) + $\sigma^2$ $\rightarrow$ Var($x_t$)= $\frac{1}{4}$Var($x_t$) + $\sigma^2 \rightarrow \frac{3}{4}$Var($x_t$) = $\sigma^2 \rightarrow$ Var($x_t$) = $\frac{4}{3}\sigma^2$.

Here's how I am doing this:

Var($x_t$) = Var($\frac{1}{2}x_{t-1} + w_t$) = Var($\frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{2}x_{t-2} + w_{t-1}) + w_t$) = Var($\frac{1}{4}x_{t-2} + \frac{1}{2}w_{t-1} + w_t$) = .... = Var($\frac{1}{2^{t-1}}x_1 + \displaystyle \sum^{t}_{s=2}\frac{1}{2^{t-s}} w_s$) = Var($\displaystyle \sum^{t}_{s=1}\frac{1}{2^{t-s}} w_s$) = $\displaystyle \sum^{t}_{s=1}\frac{1}{4^{t-s}}\sigma^2$.

Perhaps I am making a mistake in the substitution, but I do not see how the variance does not depend on the time $t$. From above, we can see that the variance is specifically dependent on $t$, even if in a geometrically decreasing manner.

Online, I have seen that I can get to the correct answer doing:

Var($\frac{1}{4}x_{t-2} + \frac{1}{2}w_{t-1} + w_t$) = .... = Var$(w_t+\frac{1}{2}w_{t-1} + \frac{1}{4}w_{t-2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n}w_{t-n} + ... ) $

Where above I have used infinite substitution to get a geometric series. In tern, I can do:

Var$(w_t+\frac{1}{2}w_{t-1} + \frac{1}{4}w_{t-2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n}w_{t-n} + ... ) $ = $\sigma^2 + \frac{1}{4}\sigma^2 + \frac{1}{16}\sigma^2 + ... = \sigma^2 (1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + ...) = \sigma^2(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}) = \frac{4}{3}\sigma^2$

which gives the correct answer. Here, the answer does not depend on time $t$ but I feel odd about saying that I have "proved" the variance does not depend on $t$ by using this - which in my is - unjustified infinite back substitution.

The more I think about it the less tangible I can make the problem. If I use the infinite back substitution, I am using values of $x_t$ indexed by negative $t$.

I guess I am looking for an answer to why my answer is "wrong" or why I am not approaching the solution correctly. Perhaps this will also answer why the infinite substitution is justified. Maybe, I can think of $t$ as being very large and thus approaching the infinite geometric series, but this still does not feel right. Any advice/ clarification/ thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The process you have defined in the first paragraph is not stationary. We have $\mathbb{Var}(x_1) = \mathbb{Var}(w_1) = \sigma^2$ and $\mathbb{Var}(x_2) = \frac{1}{4}\,\mathbb{Var}(x_1) + \mathbb{Var}(w_2) = \frac{5}{4}\,\sigma^2$.

To get a stationary AR(1) process, you need to define the first state to follow the stationary distribution - not $x_1=w_1$ but $x_1 \sim \mathrm{N}(0, \frac{4}{3}\sigma^2)$ (Exercise: try plugging this into the "here's how I'm doing this"). If the first state has a different distribution, the subsequent states will, too.  However, if $x_1$ has finite variance, the variance of $x_t$ will converge to the "stationary variance" when $t \rightarrow \infty$ - the initial state will be "forgotten".

Typically, the stationary AR.process is understood to be defined either so that the first state follows the stationary distribution or so defined to be driven by noises $\ldots,w_{-2},w_{-1},w_0,w_1,w_2,\ldots$ so that there is no "first state".